# Embeddable Python - ModuleNotFoundError for project folders

Tags: python, python-3.7

I'm trying to create an embedded python for my project.

1. I downloaded the portable python 3.7.6
2. Copied the folders from my main python installation (Lib, Scripts, include, DLLs etc..)
3. Added them to the PTH file like so :

   > ```
   > python37.zip
   > .
   > Lib
   > Lib/site-packages
   > Scripts
   > include
   > DLLs
   > doc
   > libs
   > Tools
   > tcl
   > # Uncomment to run site.main() automatically
   > #import site
   > ```

and when I tested it, I tried to run a project with the following structure :

[image: Folder Structure]

By running the command (using the embedded python):
G:\GitHub\VRoscopy\VRoscopy\Conversion\python\python.exe main.py

I get the following error :

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   
>   File "mymain.py", line 1, in <module>
>     import folder.module as m ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder'
```

However, when I try running the system python everything works normally.

Hope anyone can help me, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved by adding the project files to the PTH file, and uncommenting the "import site" like follows :

```
python37.zip . ../invesalius
../invesalius/*  # <----- added this line
Lib 
Lib/site-packages
Scripts
include
DLLs
doc
libs
Tools
tcl
# Uncomment to run site.main() automatically 
import site
```